# what is causing this seq fault in Qt QGuiApplicationPrivate::processNativeEvent()

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a simple Qt program that is reading from shared memory in a separate thread. I call a routine that waits until there is data in the shared memory segment, it unblocks and returns and then I emits a signal to the main GUI thread. The main GUI thread slot is received and in that routine I just print to std::cout that it was received then it returns--no further data processing. This program runs find for about 30 seconds then seq faults.

Running the program under gdb catches the seq fault and a back trace shows that the fault is deep in the event processing of Qt. None of my own code is involved in this seq fault. I am totally lost as to what the problem is.

Here is the gdb output. In the following gdb output, the readSM() routine is the one that blocks until there is data available to read from shared memory, and the readDataBuffer() is the slot from the main GUI thread that just returns without any further processing. There are tons of the std::cout lines for the signal and slot before the seg fault.

```
        ...many of the following 2 lines before the fault...
    DataReader::readSM(): calling m_pSharedMemory->ReadWait() 
    readDataBuffer(): entered, returning 
    DataReader::readSM(): calling m_pSharedMemory->ReadWait() 
    readDataBuffer(): entered, returning
```

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb72f5c54 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processNativeEvent(QWindow*, QByteArray const&, void*, long*) ()
from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb72f5c54 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processNativeEvent(QWindow*, QByteArray const&, void*, long*) ()
from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#1  0xb72e3ff3 in QWindowSystemInterface::handleNativeEvent(QWindow*, QByteArray const&, void*, long*) ()
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#2  0xb3f40e2d in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#3  0xb3f33170 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#4  0xb3f33dce in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#5  0xb3f74e8b in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#6  0xb701e943 in QMetaCallEvent::placeMetaCall(QObject*) ()
    from    /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0xb7021d92 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0xb7913eb4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () 
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#9  0xb7917d00 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () 
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0xb6ff3c2e in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () 
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0xb6ff68ec in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) ()
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0xb6ff6e2c in QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int) () 
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0xb704ad14 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0xb68a06d3 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0xb68a0a70 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0xb68a0b51 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0xb704b128 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0xb3f97836 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#19 0xb6ff22e6 in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0xb6ff272c in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () 
    from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0xb6ff6ed2 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0xb72f5b04 in QGuiApplication::exec() () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#23 0xb790e914 in QApplication::exec() () from /opt/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x0805034b in main ()
(gdb)`

Since I am not processing any of the data in the GUI slot, and since this program works fine for about 30 seconds with its usual signal/slots being called, I am at a loss at to what is causing this seq fault in the Qt event processing.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

-Andres

UPDATE:
thank you Andrew Medico for your suggestion to use valgrind. I never thought of using it as a debugging tool but that makes perfect sense. After using it, it became obvious that you were correct that something else was causing the problem and I finally found the cause elsewhere in my code. I was over writing a buffer.  Thanks again Andrew for your assistance.

-Andres

Comment: One possibility is that a mistake elsewhere in your program is causing heap corruption, and this is how it's manifesting. Compile at the maximum warning level to see if that catches anything obvious, and also try valgrind - it should catch invalid memory accesses when they occur.